# Getting error while running Geb test using spock and maven

Tags: geb

I'm getting the following error while running groovy scripts with maven:

> Signup Test Happy Path(SignUpPageSpec): The required page content
>   'usernamefield - SimplePageContent (owner: JiraSignupPage, args: [],
>   value: null') is not present.

Can anybody help me to resolve this error. Following are scripts:

**JiraSignUpPage.groovy**

```
package test.groovy.script
  import geb.Page;
    //import main.groovy.script.*;

   class JiraSignupPage extends Page
   {
    static url = "/vcty-jira"
    static at = { title == "System Dashboard - Velocity Jira" }
    static content = {
        usernamefield { $("input#login-form-username") }
        passwordfield { $('input#login-form-password') }
        submitButton(to: JiraSignUpResultPage) { $('button#login-form-submit') }

    }
}
```

**JiraSignUpResultPage.groovy**

```
package test.groovy.script
import geb.Page;

public class JiraSignUpResultPage extends Page
{
    static url = "/jira/secure/Dashboard.jspa"
    static at = { title == "Amit  - Jira Tracker" }

}
```

**SignUpPageSpec.groovy**

```
import spock.lang.Stepwise;
import geb.spock.GebReportingSpec;
import geb.Page;
//import main.groovy.script.*;
import test.groovy.script.*;

@Stepwise
public class SignUpPageSpec extends GebReportingSpec {

    def "Signup Test Happy Path"() {

               given: "I'm at the sign up form"
               to JiraSignupPage

               when: "I signup as a valid user"
               usernamefield = "xyz"
               passwordfield = "xyz"
               submitButton.click()

               then: "I'm at the result page"
               at JiraSignUpResultPage

           }
}
```

**GebConfig.groovy**

```
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver

import geb.waiting.*;

driver = { new FirefoxDriver() }

baseUrl = "http://172.17.48.65:8080/"

reportsDir = new File("target/geb-reports")

reportOnTestFailureOnly = true

waiting {
    timeout = 20
    retryInterval = 0.5
}
```

I'm running mvn.test to run these test. It causes browser to open but ends up with error.

Answer (score 0):

The error tells you that your `usernamefield` content definition returned an empty navigator - an input with id `login-form-username` has not been found on the page you navigated to.

Comment: But I'm on the correct page and also I recheck the id of input field and it is same as I define but still getting error.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your page is not fully loaded.
Try adding `usernamefield.displayed` to 'at' block
or add 'wait' to page element

```
 usernamefield(wait: true) { $("input#login-form-username") }
```

Comment: Page is fully loaded but still test are getting failed. I have put wait for uernamefield but still getting same problem.

Comment: Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 63.14 sec <<< FAILURE! Signup Test Happy Path(SignUpPageSpec)  Time elapsed: 60.167 sec  <<< ERROR!   geb.waiting.WaitTimeoutException: condition did not pass in 20.0 seconds (failed with exception) Caused by: Assertion failed: 

$("input#login-form-username")
|
[]

 at test.groovy.script.JiraSignupPage._clinit__closure2_closure3(JiraSignupPage.groovy:12) attest.groovy.script.JiraSignupPage._clinit__closure2_closure3(JiraSignupPage.groovy)

Comment: Maybe there's something to do with the hyphens in id? Can you try $("input[id='login-form-username']") ?